# How to filter types of Webforms with Views

Tags: views, webforms

I am trying to create a simple View of webforms to display a list of currently available jobs.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
Webform1
description description description description...
[Read more]


Webform2
description description description description...
[Read more]


Webform3
description description description description...
[Read more]
```

I thought webforms would be a decent solution considering I can add/remove them once the job listing is expired. It is also very easy to go through submissions.

Only issue I am having is that the contact form I have is also a webform.

So I am getting some unwanted items in my view query. I am having a difficult time figuring out a simple yet robust solution to filter the different types of webforms.

The only filter criteria available for a view of webforms are `Webform: Node` & `Webform: Status` and I believe neither will help me accomplish what I need.

**Anybody got any ideas of what I could do to differentiate between webforms for views filtering?**

Comment: So, I'm not sure that webforms will do what you want. I think you want a custom content type of Jobs, which are easily filtered in views.

Comment: @nizz0k users need to be able to attach resume' and cover letter and I need to be able to go through all the submissions, need to send confirmation emails and limit user submissions. And I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel or have 50 modules when web-forms handles 99.9% of it. Unless you know of a simple solution that falls under that scope i believe webforms are a better solution overall.

Comment: You don't need 50 modules. I'd say you could do this with a "job" content type, a flag, and a single webform for submission. So, you have your jobs content type, users flag the job/jobs they are applying for, and finally submit through a webform which has the job/list of jobs. Same basic concept but doesn't make you generate tons of separate webforms for each job.

Comment: if you think that will work, I can give you more details on the implementation and the tiny little custom module to get a list of the flagged jobs.

Comment: Not 100% sure how but I have the option to filter by two more options: Global Combine Fields, and Fields Comparison, but I don't think those are helpful to you either.

Comment: It's a very neat solution thank you, I always forget about the flag module. But to be honest I don't want that type of UX. I want a user story of: user clicks job, user uploads files, user submits. There won't be many jobs (if any) for this website so managing 1 job to 1 webform is not a problem. If i removed my contact form from webforms then my solution will satisfy the clients needs 100% I was thinking about swapping my contact webform to a entityform or vice versa but I really want to know if there is a solution to distinguish between types of webforms.

Comment: So, just from looking around there doesn't appear to be, although you could use webform views to have a view of jobs in your job submission webform..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Webform functionality on all the different content types. You don't have to use the Webform content type which comes pre-packaged with the module.

Make a new content type, and go to: `/admin/config/content/webform` and enable webform functionality on the new content type you created. Then add the webform to it.

Then you just need to filter by content type on Views.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the webform view module, this module let's you place a view in your webform.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this addresses the question about create a view of webforms and not place a view in a webform?

Comment: I'm not sure the functionality op is looking for is possible, I am suggesting a parallel development that would achieve the sAme end